¿Cómo creo una lista a partir de una cadena en Python?
Estoy iniciando un curso de Python para principiantes y uno de los ejercicios que nos pusieron fue el siguiente:
Crea una lista de la cadena dada, el separador es '_',
#reemplaza las XXX para lograrlo.

#la lista debe ser
 
#['grecia', 'diego', 'celeste', 'kevin', 'gaby', 'guillermo']

e2   = 'grecia_diego_celeste_kevin_gaby_guillermo'

e2_l = e2.[xxx]('X')

El curso que tomo es online por lo que la calificación no es revisada por un tutor, sino por un sistema automatizado; si no sustituyo las X y lo resuelvo de otra forma el sistema me lo califica como incorrecto.
Me podrían apoyar por favor. Muchas gracias.
PD. Las 3 xxx van entre corchetes pero el formato de las preguntas no me permite integralos.

Bienvenida a [es.so], mírate el método str.split()

Me parece que intentaste decir e2_l = e2."xxx"('X').

¡Hola!
En ese caso, cuando queremos separar una cadena de texto y convertirlo en lista, existe un método muy utilizado y es un método que se aplica a los str.
str.split(separator, maxsplit)

Este método nos ayuda mucho a la hora de separar cadenas de textos; un caso muy común es cuando queremos separar una cadena de texto por espacio " ", por comas "," o por cualquier otro caracter.
En caso que no le pases ningún argumento al método split(), el los separa por defecto por espacio entre cada palabra.

# Caso que no le pasemos ningún argumento a la función.
saludo = "Hola Mundo"
imprimir_saludo = saludo.split()
print(imprimir_saludo) # resultado sería una lista ["Hola", "Mundo"]

# Caso que lo quieras separar por espacio
saludo = "Hola Mundo"
imprimir_saludo = saludo.split(" ")
print(imprimir_saludo) # resultado sería una lista ["Hola", "Mundo"]

# Caso que lo quieras separar por coma
saludos = "Hola Mundo, soy python"
imprimir_saludo = saludo.split(",")
print(imprimir_saludo) # resultado sería una lista ["Hola Mundo", " soy python"]

# Caso que lo quieras separar por underscore
saludos = "Hola_Mundo_soy_python"
imprimir_saludo = saludo.split("_")
print(imprimir_saludo) # resultado sería una lista ["Hola", "Mundo", "soy", "python"]


Y el segundo argumento es opcional y nos indica la cantidad de veces que quieres aplicar la separación, por defecto, el maneja siempre -1 que hace referencia a toda la coincidencia del texto.

# Caso que queremos solamente separar la primera coincidencia
saludo = "Hola_Mundo_Soy_Python"
imprimir_saludo = saludo.split("_", 1)
print(imprimir_saludo) # resultado sería una lista ["Hola", "Mundo_Soy_Python"]


Para resolver ese ejercicio debes aplicarle el método split a la cadena de texto.
En tu caso tienes esto e2_l = e2.[xxx]('X'), es decir, que e2_l es igual a e2 (texto con todo los nombres separados por un underscore) pero en donde va las x debes ponerle el método split() y ese método debe recibir como primer argumento el separador, en este caso sería el underscore (_)
Así debería quedarte el código
e2 = 'grecia_diego_celeste_kevin_gaby_guillermo'
e2_l = e2.split('_')

#la respuesta va a ser un arreglo de los nombres separados

Eso debería funcionarte.

Aprovecha de explicar otras aplicaciones del método split() para casos típicos: eliminar espacios, separar por comas, separación acotada.

Espero quede más claro cómo poder aplicar el método split() en Python con esta explicación.

¡Hola!, realmente es algo muy sencillo, simplemente tienes que utilizar la función "split", que se encuentra disponible para todas las cadenas de texto (str). Esta función lo que hace es convertir una cadena de texto en una lista utilizando un separador. En este caso obtendrás una lista en la que aparecen todas las palabras separadas sin el símbolo "_". Para utilizarlo en este caso, es tan simple como lo siguiente:
#la lista debe ser
#['grecia', 'diego', 'celeste', 'kevin', 'gaby', 'guillermo']

e2   = 'grecia_diego_celeste_kevin_gaby_guillermo'

# Con esto conseguiremos separar la cadena de texto como te indicaba.
e2_l = e2.split("_")

